# SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue finishTransaction: not finishing transaction

Tags: iphone, ios5, in-app-purchase

We have two IAPs in our app that purchase Non-Renewing subscriptions.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray*)transactions
```

is being called correctly and during:

```
- (void) CompleteTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction*)tran
```

we are calling:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: tran];
```

We can successfully purchase either of the subscriptions once with our test account.

Yet when we try to repurchase the items, to test when you subscription expires, we get this AlertView:

```
"You've Already purchased this in-app purchase but it hasn't been downloaded"
```

We are in Xcode 4.2 on the iOS 5 sdk/iOS 4.1 deployment target.

UPDATE:

Looks like this is a bug in iOS 5.0.1 on the device.

I am able to re-purchase the IAP items on an iPod Touch running iOS 4.1. I can build the app for SDK 4.1, 4.3 or 5.0 and it still works. However, if I build the app for SDK 4.1, 4.3 or 5.0 and try to run on my iOS 5.0.1 device, it never works.

This is is error from the iOS 5.0.1 device:

```
Failure:Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=2 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x1f90f0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple confirmed this bug. I submitted a bug report and had a back and forth with Apple Engineer.

Comment: Apparently this is a bug since iOS 3 never solved properly. The problem is that according to several users on posts around the web, Apple support blames developers when customers contact them to complain. For that reason, customers probably bury apps with 1 star reviews, when Apple is the one to blame. If you have come with a workaround, please let me know.

Comment: Here's the bug number: 10408387 @kcharwood